# Multiple DHCP Offers - Which is selected?

Tags: ipv4, protocol-theory, dhcp, security

I have created a testing scenario in VMWare for a man in the middle attack using DHCP spoofing. It's for a college project.

Windows 8 machine bridged to host adapter
Kali linux bridged to host adapter
Host connected to router X.X.X.1/24
Using ettercap I'm trying to give a fake DHCP lease, pointing to Kali linux ip address X.X.X.161. However Windows 8 refuses to accept the DHCP offer, even tough it arrives before router's offer (tested with wireshark). Tried: ipconfig /release & ipconfig /renew

I read Windows prefer to select a DHCP offer of a previous accepted gateway address. But I tried to disable/reinstall network card and restart Windows. No change.

What is the criteria for select a DHCP offer when there are more than one? I read everywhere that the one wich arrives first is selected, but it doesn't appears to be the case.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here, as are questions about protocols above OSI layer-4.

Answer (score 2):

I have troubleshooted this in a real scenario.

In Windows 7 with Wifi Intel driver, it just gets the first DHCP offer to arrive.

Comment: As a general rule, the first answer *always* wins.